# How to have superscript with notification title

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have some local notifications and I'd like local notification title to have some characters as superscript.

I'm not able to find anything on it so far.

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: You can’t use an attributed string in a notification.  You might be able to do what you want when the user expands the notification. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications

Comment: @Paulw11 - Can we change the title with superscript when the user expands ?

Answer (score 0):

Notification title supports only string not attributed string.
We usually show some kind of common symbol as super script such as TM - Trade Mark etc..

These kind of common symbols are available as unicode which you can directly use in a string

```
 let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Test \u{2122}"
```

In the above backward slash means some escape sequence and u means it's a unicode and you have to the unicode number into the flower bracket.

There are so many unicode symbols like this that can be used as a part of string and no need of attributed string at all.

Comment: I never knew about this unicode can do wonders like with string. Thanks